# Pass the Selected Master DropDownList item by jQuery and retrive and bind items for Slave DropDownList

Tags: jquery, asp.net, httphandler

I have 2 DropDownList and a jQuery script with HttpHandler in server side I dont Know how pass the parameter by jQuery and how retrive Multi Items for bind in Slave Dropdown one.

this is my Default.aspx code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org
/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="Sample001.Default" %>
<script src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
        <asp:Label ID="masterlbl" Text="Master" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="Mastercs">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Item1" Value="Item1" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Item2" Value="Item2" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Item3" Value="Item3" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Item4" Value="Item4" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Item5" Value="Item5" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td>
            <asp:Label ID="slavelbl" Text="Slave" runat="server" />
            </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="slavecs">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server" />
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('span.Mastercs select').change(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'MyHandler.ashx',
                    dataType: "text",
                    data: "ItemSelected=" + $('select#ddl1').val(),
                    async: true,
                    success: function (data) { Handler_Success(data); }
                });
            });
            function Handler_Success(data) {
                $('select#ddl2').empty();
                $.each(data, function (i, slaveValue) {
$('select#ddl2').append($('<option>/option>')
.val(data.Value).html(data.Text));
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is My handler:

```
public class SlaveValue {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    public class SlaveValueHandler : IHttpHandler {
        public bool IsReusable {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
            string valueSelected = context.Request["ItemSelected"];
            List<SlaveValue> slaveValues = new List<SlaveValue>();
            SlaveValue sv;

            sv = new SlaveValue();
        sv.Text = "SV1";
        sv.Value = valueSelected + "s1";
        slaveValues.Add(sv);

        sv = new SlaveValue();
        sv.Text = "SV2";
        sv.Value = valueSelected + "s2";
        slaveValues.Add(sv);

        sv = new SlaveValue();
        sv.Text = "SV3";
        sv.Value = valueSelected + "s3";
        slaveValues.Add(sv);

    string responseText = 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(slaveValues);
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
            context.Response.Write(responseText);
        }
    }
```

When the ddl1(DropDownList) changed I can see in Firebug the Response correctly. but the  ddl2(DropDownList) didn't see any change:
this is Firebug Response:

```
[{"Value":"Item3s1","Text":"SV1"},{"Value":"Item3s2","Text":"SV2"},
{"Value":"Item3s3","Text":"SV3"}]
```

Also when I change the Script Success Method to the following code the ddl2(DropDownList) bind correctly. :

```
function Handler_Success(data) {
                $('select#ddl2').empty();
                $.each(data, function (i, slaveValue) {
                    $('select#ddl2').append($('<option>
    </option>').val('sv1').html('s1'));
                });
            }
```

as you see the ddl2(DropDownList) bind Correctly with above code,
Where is the Problem? 
Why I can see the response in Firebug but the binding not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can be useful this very like as your problem an have a complete step by step solution:

[use return value of json in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993160/use-return-value-of-json-in-jquery-ajax-script-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

Jquery AJAX Call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'MyHandler.ashx',
    dataType: "text",
    data: "ItemSelected=" + $('select.ddl1').val();,
    async: true,
    success: function(data) { Handler_Success(data); },
    error: function(er) { Handler_Error(er); }
});
```

Handler:

```
public class SlaveValue
{
   public string Value {get; set;}
   public string Text {get; set;}
}
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    string valueSelected = context.Request["ItemSelected"]
    List<SlaveValue> slaveValues = new List<SlaveValue>();
    //POPULATE SLAVEVALUES HERE
    //JSON-ify the list
    string responseText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(slaveValues);
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
    context.Response.Write(responseText);
}
```

AJAX Handler

```
function Handler_Success(data) {
    //clear out old options (if any)
    $('select.ddl2').empty()
    $.each(data, function(i, slaveValue) {
        $('select.ddl2').append(
            $('<option></option>').val(slaveValue.Value).html(slaveValue.Text)
        )
    }
}
```

I am using Json.NET to serialize the collection of SlaveValues.[It can be downloaded here](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx)

Comment: Shai, Thanks for response, I do as you said, but there is a Problem in bind to SlaveDropDownList, I edit my question, you can see my new code in above, do you know where is the problem?

Comment: @Saeid: If I am reading your code correctly:      $('select#ddl2').append($('<option>  </option>').val('sv1').html('s1'));  you are not actually binding to the returned data. The code just adds options with "sv1" and "s1". My original code had a bug. I edited it now. basically the append should look like this: $('select#ddl2').append($('<option>
    </option>').val(slaveValue.Value).html(slaveValue.Text));

Comment: I try exactly what you said, but not work, and about this code $('select#ddl2').append($('<option> </option>').val('sv1').html('s1')); that you mentioned, this is not main binding, I said with this code that not have any return value I can Bind correctly, but with return value append to slave ddl show nothing.

Comment: Ok let's figure this out... let's place a couple of breakpoints: put a breakpoint at these lines and let me know what the output is. What is "responseText" here: context.Response.Write(responseText); What is "data" here: $('select.ddl2').empty(). What is "slaveValue" here: $('select#ddl2').append($('<option>....